# Sending txt file from React to 3rd party via Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

Im trying to upload a simple .txt from React to NodeJS. I see the file being sent to node as a promise that awaits to an object. But I seem to need a Buffer string (?) to send the file via axios or similar.I keep getting errors that I have the wrong input type for making a Buffer... But what should I use here?

React:

```
  function onChange({
    target: {
      validity,
      files: [file],
    },
  }) {
    if (validity.valid) mutate({ variables: { file } });
  }

  
      {/* @TEMP testing file upload */}
      <input type="file" multiple required onChange={onChange} />
```

Node:

```
 var newBuffer = new Buffer(file, "base64");
      var formData = {
        file: {
          value: newBuffer,
          options: {
            filename: file.filename,
            contentType: file.mimetype,
          },
        },
      };
      let formHeaders = formData.getHeaders();

      let res = await axios.post(
        `https://site.nodejs.net/rest`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            ...formHeaders,
            Authorization: `Basic ${TOKEN}`,
            Accept: "application/json"
          },
        }
      );
```

ERROR:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: @BurningAlcohol 
ERROR::::>>>>  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object

Comment: What does this have to do with Jira, or Jira plugins?

Comment: @tgdavies it's a query regarding their API usage via NodeJS. Did you have any ideas or did you want attention?

Comment: @tgdavies I found several related unanswered Atlassian tickets if you're looking.
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-do-we-attach-multiple-images-with-JIRA-rest-attachments-api/qaq-p/803926

Comment: That ticket is talking about a problem talking to a particular Jira endpoint. Your question seems to be a problem between your react frontend and your Nodejs backend. It doesn't mention Jira. The incorrect tags may put off people who would otherwise read your question. By all means edit your question to explain where Jira fits in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Multer**, it is a node.js middleware for working with multipart/form-data, which is primarily used for uploading files.

`npm install —-save multer`